# How to merge methods into one

Tags: apex, class, update, merge

How can I merge these two methods that just set the date for child records when the parent record changes? Or should I just keep them separate?

```
   public with sharing class Tables {

   public static void updateTableDateSeats(Map<Id, Team__c> 
   newTeams, Map<Id, Team__c> oldTeams){
    Set<Id> teamIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Id id : newTeams.keyset()){
        if(newTeams.get(id).Filled__c != 'Immediate' && 
    oldTeams.get(id).Filled__c =='Immediate'){
            teamIds.add(id);
        }
    }
    if(teamIds.size()> 0){
        List<table__c> tablesToUpdate = 
   tableQueried.getTablesSection1(teamIds);
        for(table__c t : tablesToUpdate){
            t.Date_filled__c = System.today();
        }
        update tablesToUpdate;
    }
}
  public static void updateTableDateSeatsSection2(Map<Id, Team__c> 
   newTeams, Map<Id, Team__c> oldTeams){
    Set<Id> teamIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Id id : newTeams.keyset()){
        if(newTeams.get(id).Booked__c ==true && 
    oldTeams.get(id).booked__c ==false){
            teamIds.add(id);
        }
    }
    if(teamIds.size()> 0){
        List<table__c> tablesToUpdate = 
   tableQueried.getTablesSection2(teamIds);
        for(table__c t : tablesToUpdate){
            t.Date_filled__c = System.today();
        }
        update tablesToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can merge the two methods into one like this way.

```
public static void updateTableMergeMethod(Map<Id, Team__c> 
   newTeams, Map<Id, Team__c> oldTeams)
   {
        Set<Id> teamIds = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> secondteamIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Id id : newTeams.keyset())
        {
            if(newTeams.get(id).Filled__c != 'Immediate' && 
            oldTeams.get(id).Filled__c =='Immediate')
            {
                teamIds.add(id);
            }
            if(newTeams.get(id).Booked__c ==true && 
            oldTeams.get(id).booked__c ==false){
                secondteamIds.add(id);
            }
        }

        List<table__c> lstTable = new List<table__c>();

        if(teamIds.size()> 0)
        {   
            lstTable.add(tableQueried.getTablesSection1(teamIds));          
        }
        if(secondteamIds.size()>0)
        {
            lstTable.add(tableQueried.getTablesSection2(secondteamIds));                    
        }
        for(table__c t : lstTable){
                t.Date_filled__c = System.today();
            }
        update lstTable;
   }
```

Comment: I have two different tableQueried.getTablesSection1 and tableQueried.getTablesSection2, only tablesSection2 is used in the above method.

Comment: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(List<Table__c>) from the type List<Table__c> (Line: 18, Column: 36) it is saying my TableQueried does not exist

Comment: What do you mean by not defined?

Comment: TableQueried is not defined, I have given you the approach, follow this and rectify the issue